# Qt / QML не запускается готовый exe

Tags: c++, qt, qml, mingw

Слил экзешник от QML проекта в отдельную папку и добавил библиотек через windeployqt, но при запуске экзешника ничего не происходит вообще, даже ошибки не выбивает. Хотя если кинуть его в mingw492_32\bin все прекрасно работает.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 2):

Установите [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) и посмотрите каких dll-библиотек недостаточно. Поскольку используете MinGW, то одним windeployqt не обойдетесь.

Скорее всего, не хватает следующих библиотек:

- libstdc++-6.dll
- libwinpthread-1.dll
- libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll

Comment: пробовал он вроде находил что-то но при указании папки mingw492_32\bin для добавления он не видел там нужных библиотек хотя повторюсь в bin все работает

Comment: сейчас проверю  ваши библиотеки

Comment: не помогло, libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll отсутствовала но dependency walker о ней не говорил, скачал её кинул в папку на всякий, но все равно не сработало

Comment: Если отсутствовала, то вы используете SEH для обработки исключений, посмотрите библиотеку libgcc_s_seh-1.dll. Но чтобы не гадать, просто посмотрите список dll, которые walker не находит. Возможно, вы используете еще что-то стороннее.

Comment: seh тоже не помог, walker выдает всякую муть наподобие "API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL" но в папке  bin же все прекрасно работает и без этого

Comment: Системные библиотеки пропустите, ниже прокрутите, где пойдут qt и mingw-библиотеки. Вот среди них надо посмотреть

Comment: там все MS-WIN библиотеки которые с вопросиками и одна IESHIMS.DLL, с другими все в порядке

Answer (score 1):

Перед запуском windeployqt.exe забыл закинуть qml файл в папку с exeшником

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно подкинуть в папку с exe следующие папки и файлы: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уже решил проблему, надо было файл qml в ту же папку кидать где и экзешник перед windeployqt, но спасибо за ответ